# GraphConv vs GCNConv pytorch.geometric

Tags: pytorch-geometric, graph-neural-network

I'm trying to compare 2 models GraphConv and GCNConv for my project. According to the tutorial provided by pytorch GraphConv preserves central node information by omiting neighborhood normalisation. The tutorial shows GraphConv has improved the test accuracy to 82% from 76% in the case of GCNConv model. However, in my case GraphConv increased the training accuracy from 89% (by GCNConv) to 93% but no change in test accuracy i.e. 88% (similiar in GraphConv and GCNConv). I'm keeping rest of the parameters same, so what could be the reason(s)? Is there any way to increase the test accuracy? Thank you, below is the link to pytorch tutorial I mentioned.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1I8a0DfQ3fI7Njc62__mVXUlcAleUclnb?usp=sharing#scrollTo=ecJCNRmT2RsF

I tried to compare GraphConv and GCNConv, GraphConv is supposed to give me better result on test accuracy but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Could you share your code for GraphConv? As the random parts of the code can alter the output I think running it a few times (if your code is working correclty) can show slightly different results, for eample, check my architecture for the network,

```
    self.conv1 = GraphConv(dataset.num_node_features, hidden_channels)
    self.conv2 = GraphConv(hidden_channels, hidden_channels)
    self.conv3 = GraphConv(hidden_channels, hidden_channels)
    self.lin = Linear(hidden_channels, dataset.num_classes)
```

This would yield a Test accuracy around 84 percent, As you can see in a sample run:

```
Epoch: 189, Train Acc: 0.8600, Test Acc: 0.7368
Epoch: 190, Train Acc: 0.9333, Test Acc: 0.7895
Epoch: 191, Train Acc: 0.9133, Test Acc: 0.7895
Epoch: 192, Train Acc: 0.9333, Test Acc: 0.7895
Epoch: 193, Train Acc: 0.9333, Test Acc: 0.7895
Epoch: 194, Train Acc: 0.9333, Test Acc: 0.7895
Epoch: 195, Train Acc: 0.9333, Test Acc: 0.8158
Epoch: 196, Train Acc: 0.9133, Test Acc: 0.7895
Epoch: 197, Train Acc: 0.9467, Test Acc: 0.8158
Epoch: 198, Train Acc: 0.9467, Test Acc: 0.8158
Epoch: 199, Train Acc: 0.9333, Test Acc: 0.7895
Epoch: 200, Train Acc: 0.9333, Test Acc: 0.8421
```